# Should I Buy Cordless Drill/Driver From USA And Use It In My Country?

Tags: electrical, screws, drill

I want to purchase **[DeWalt 18V Cordless Drill/Driver](http://bit.ly/rQPepj)** from USA where electricity standard is 120V - 60Hz and use it in my country with transformer where standard is 220V-230V - 50Hz but there will be 10Hz of electricity frequency difference. Although people say differently, i would still like to know if such option is worthwhile given i save a lot of money.

What specifications must be transformer to fit cordless drill/driver and remain stable? What other things besides voltage should i take into account?

Comment: Unrelated to the voltage/charging issue, it will not have a valid warranty outside of the country, especially if you are not charging with the correct voltage/frequency. If I were going to buy an expensive drill, I'd want to have it under a valid warranty.

Answer (score 9):

I would buy part number DW9116220. This is the 220 volt charger for the battery system. Then buy the drill separately and you're good to go.